# CSS - How to Add Lines Between Just the Columns in a Table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am trying to get my right border to go straight down the table column as in the image below:

[image: Pic 1]

Mine looks like this:

[image: Pic 2]

If you look closely the line does not go all the way down to the bottom and it looks scattered towards the bottom.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="Popular">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_acb8138a-77ea-40fe-96fd-237156495af3.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
<td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_670662b7-080f-41a4-934b-2c0bc6a821a6.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
<td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_d173fb5e-b78b-4aa5-a481-6b744ad8e041.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
<td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_bd6e7f09-f4fe-44f9-96c9-fab317f09644.jpg" width="230px" height="200px"></td>
<td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_34952e34-5414-456c-8b8f-b469f55b4fdc.jpg" width="230px" height="200px"></td>
<td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_97c737b9-1e44-41c4-9c47-c92b7ddd2455.jpg" width="233px" height="200px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><h4>$0.45</h4></td>
<td><h4>$2.59</h4></td>
<td><h4>$1.90</h4></td>
<td><h4>$2.59lb</h4></td>
<td><h4>$6.29</h4></td>
<td><h4>$0.99</h4></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Banana</td>
<td>Avocado</td>
<td>Full Apple</td>
<td>Yellow Onion</td>
<td>Strawberries</td>
<td>Large Lemon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>-0.41lbs</td>
<td>each</td>
<td>-0.5lbs</td>
<td>n/a</td>
<td>16Oz</td>
<td>each</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.Popular{
background:white;
height:350px;
width:80%;
margin:0 0 0 100px;
}
.Popular td{
border-right:1px solid gray;
}

.Popular ul{
margin:0;
}
.Popular li{
list-style:none;
}
.Popular h4{
margin:0;
}
.column2{
border-right:1px solid gray;
padding:5px 10px;
}
```

UPDATE 1

I added the border colapse property and it did get rid of the spacing, however, the line is still not going all the way to the bottom see image below:

[image: Pic 3]

UPDATE 2

With help it looks like the image below (see the first row not the second row). The words are more spread out from eachother and the spacing on the bottom is gone as it supposed to look like in the first image.

[image: Pic 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my code below - I've added comments to the CSS.

```css
.Popular {
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 100px;
 overflow: auto;
}

/* Collapse the border, to prevent gaps between the table rows/cells */
.Popular table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Add 1 em padding to left/right of all cells (of all rows after the first, to not mess with the images) */
.Popular tr + tr td {
 padding: 0 1em;
}

/* Add 3em of padding to the bottom of all table cells, in the last table row; this replaces setting a height on the parent container - to simulate height */
.Popular tr:last-child td {
 padding-bottom: 3em;
}

.Popular td {
 margin: 0;
 border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.Popular ul {
 margin:0;
}

.Popular li {
 list-style:none;
}

.Popular h4 {
 margin:0;
}

.column2 {
 border-right:1px solid gray;
 padding:5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Popular">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_acb8138a-77ea-40fe-96fd-237156495af3.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
   <td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_670662b7-080f-41a4-934b-2c0bc6a821a6.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
   <td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_d173fb5e-b78b-4aa5-a481-6b744ad8e041.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
   <td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_bd6e7f09-f4fe-44f9-96c9-fab317f09644.jpg" width="230px" height="200px"></td>
   <td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_34952e34-5414-456c-8b8f-b469f55b4fdc.jpg" width="230px" height="200px"></td>
   <td class="column2"><img src="assets/large_97c737b9-1e44-41c4-9c47-c92b7ddd2455.jpg" width="233px" height="200px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><h4>$0.45</h4></td>
   <td><h4>$2.59</h4></td>
   <td><h4>$1.90</h4></td>
   <td><h4>$2.59lb</h4></td>
   <td><h4>$6.29</h4></td>
   <td><h4>$0.99</h4></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Banana</td>
   <td>Avocado</td>
   <td>Full Apple</td>
   <td>Yellow Onion</td>
   <td>Strawberries</td>
   <td>Large Lemon</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>-0.41lbs</td>
   <td>each</td>
   <td>-0.5lbs</td>
   <td>n/a</td>
   <td>16Oz</td>
   <td>each</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

With this border-spacing and empty-cells properties have no effect

Comment: See my update it sort of worked. Still can't figure out how to get the line to go all the way.

Comment: Yeah, because your div (with the background-color) around your table is higher than the table itself, just add height: 100% on the table

Comment: Or you can also put the background-color on the table instead of the div

Comment: The height worked, however, the spacing towards the bottom is gone (see first pic of how it is supposed to look). I am working on it though right now to see if I can get it just right.

Comment: What we can do now is this: `table tr:last-child td{padding-bottom: 40px;}`. The last row is selected with 'last-child', and then we go into the td's and set the padding on the bottom. Hope thats it for now :)

Answer (score 1):

I would change how you are formatting your table. Instead of putting everything in a single table, try nesting a table for each fruit inside of your table.

Here is an example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="column2">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="assets/large_acb8138a-77ea-40fe-96fd-237156495af3.jpg" width="235px" height="200px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><h4>$0.45</h4></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Banana</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>-0.41lbs</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        // Other products would follow the same convention
    </tr>
</table>
```

And then, for your CSS, get rid of this:

```
.Popular td {
    border-right:1px solid gray;
}
```

because you won't need the borders on every `<td>`, just the `<td>` that contains the nested `<table>`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. If you see the 4th image and the second row that is how the code came out. It was not what I was looking for but thank you for the attempt.